# Previous and Next posts

Tags: custom-post-types, previous-post-link

I use the following code for displaying the previous post thumbnail with links:

```
<?php 
      $prevPost = get_previous_post(true); 
      $prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($prevPost->ID, array(150,150) );
      previous_post_link( '%link', $prevThumbnail ); 
?>
```

The problem is that I get the correct link for the previous post but the thumbnail that is displayed is of the current post and not of the previous post. I am using this for a single template of a custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
<?php 
    $prevPost = get_previous_post();

    foreach ($prevPost as $postPrev) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail($postPrev->ID)) {
            $prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($postPrev->ID, array(150,150) );
            previous_post_link( '%link', $prevThumbnail );
        }
    }
?>
```